# How to get MAC Address and OS Name in react-js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mac-address

I want to get the client MacAddress And OS name

```
     import pkg from 'getmac'
     import getMAC, { isMAC } from 'getmac'
     
     changeCaptcha =() => {
         this.reloadCaptcha()
         console.log(getMAC())
     }
```

but it's not working

- Error: Failed to get the MAC address

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the getmac package doc, it runs over NodeJS and won't run on client side (for obvious security reasons).

You may get the OS name which is transfered by the browser in the referrer.

Why would you need this information in the first place?